# How can I add to the system 'Path' variable and have the new path used by a DLL immediately?

Tags: java, windows, dll, jri

Here's the situation. I am attempting to load the JRI for R integration in Java.

Here's what I know to make it work:
-Make sure that the path to the JRI DLL is in the java.library.path (so java can load the native library).
-Make sure that the path to the R DLL is in the system path (so the system can resolve a DLL dependency).

If both of these are true before my application loads, the library will load with no problem.
However I am having problems with loading it if I try to do it automatically, without use involvement.

Here's how I am trying to make it work:
-If the JRI DLL is not in the java.library.path, add it at runtime using reflection and try to load the library again immediately - this works great.
-If the R DLL is not in the system 'Path' add it using the 'setx command.

The second step is where I am hitting huge problems - I still see an error with finding the R DLL (which is a dependency of the JRI DLL).

My code sets the system 'Path' as it should immediately, as I check this in the control panel, however loading the JRI library fails on a dependency.
I know setting the path correctly fixes the dependency issue if I set it before running my application, so why it does not work in this case I do not understand.
If I kill my application and start it from scratch, it works fine as the 'Path' was set from the last time it was run.

When a dependency failure occurs on loading a DLL, where is the error actually happening?
Does Java look for the dependency of the JRI DLL? I had assumed Java played no part in the resolving a dependency of a DLL, was I wrong?
If the operating system is responsible for resolving the dependency of a DLL, then why is my 'Path' change not recognised?
Do environment variables get passed to a DLL when Java tries to load it?

I should add that I am developing this in Netbeans, however I see the same behaviour if I build a JAR and run that directly in the terminal. I often see that a 'Path' update is not seen until a restart of Netbeans, however I had thought that a DLL resolving its dependencies would use the 'Path' directly.

It's pretty frustrating so it'd be great to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: `setx` doesn't change the environment variables for the current process, or for child processes, only for brand new processes.  (To be more precise, only for processes created by applications such as Explorer that explicitly look for changes in the environment variable settings.)  In your case, you need to change the environment variables for the Java process.  I'm not sure how you do that, hopefully someone else can answer, but `setx` won't do it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston My confusion is whether the 'thing' (?) resolving DLL dependencies is receiving its environment through Java, or whether it is a system component and entirely separate from the the process hierarchy I create when I start my application. Does loading a native library cause a sub-process to be created?

Comment: I should also add that I can (and do) change the environment variables in the Java process, but this appears to have no effect on the resolution of the DLL's dependencies, though it does allow my DLL to be found in the first place (by Java).

Comment: In cases where the PATH is used in resolving dependencies (which seems to be true here, since setting it ahead of time works) then it is read from the environment variable block of the process that is loading the DLL.  The first thing you should double-check is whether you've successfully changed the process environment variables.  You can do this with Process Explorer, which is available free of charge from the MS web site.  (This will also show you whether there are any sub-processes or not.)